# PHP Array to CSV using header on the Column not Row

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am a novice PHP (As months old) and I searched a lot about my question but couldn't find a helpful solution or tutorial about this.

I have created a code for PHP CSV output and the output is showing in a list of rows in the CSV, but they are in the row section (they are correct and working fine) I am looking more changing row into column

I have searched but yet to find any helpful resource.

I hope you can provide me with some tutorial or solution or advice to implement it by myself. As I'm a novice please provide easy to implement solutions.

Here is a code I wrote and it's working fine

```
<?php

// Database Connection
include ('../sql/mainSql.php');

// filename for export
$csv_filename = 'Total_Settlement_UK_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';

// get Users
$query = "SELECT settlement_id, settlement_start_date,settlement_end_date,total_amount FROM settlements WHERE total_amount";
if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    exit(mysqli_error($conn));
}

$users = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $users[] = $row;
    }
}

header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('settlement_id', 'settlement_start_date', 'settlement_end_date', 'total_amount'));

if (count($users) > 0) {
    foreach ($users as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
}
?>
```

the results is fine and you can see screenshot.

[image: Screenshot1]

However, I would like this Row header into column header.

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Have you tried an array_flip() on the array that is returned from mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) - and then continue processing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prepare your array in such a way that you store all your respective data together.

```
/* Prepare your final array */
$userDetails = [
    'settlement_id' => [],
    'settlement_start_date' => [],
    'settlement_end_date' => [],
    'total_amount' => []
];

/* This will store the data to particular column, if no data is set then will set empty by default */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $newArray['settlement_id'][]        = (isset($row['settlement_id'])) ? $row['settlement_id'] : '';
    $newArray['settlement_start_date'][]    = (isset($row['settlement_start_date'])) ? $row['settlement_start_date'] : '';
    $newArray['settlement_end_date'][]  = (isset($row['settlement_end_date'])) ? $row['settlement_end_date'] : '';
    $newArray['total'][]            = (isset($row['total'])) ? $row['total'] : '';
}
```

The following is the example

```
<?php

$resultArray = [
    [
        'settlement_id' => 1,
        'settlement_start_date' => '2017-01-01',
        'settlement_end_date' => '2018-01-01',
        'total' => 2015
    ],
    [
        'settlement_id' => 2,
        'settlement_start_date' => '2017-01-01',
        'settlement_end_date' => '2018-01-01',
        'total' => 2016
    ],
    [
        'settlement_id' => 3,
        'settlement_start_date' => '2017-01-01',
        'settlement_end_date' => '2018-01-01',
        'total' => 2017
    ],
    [
        'settlement_id' => 4,
        'settlement_start_date' => '2017-01-01',
        'settlement_end_date' => '2018-01-01',
        'total' => 2018
    ],
    [
        'settlement_id' => 5,
        'settlement_start_date' => '2017-01-01',
        'settlement_end_date' => '2018-01-01',
        'total' => 2019
    ]
];

$newArray = [
    'settlement_id' => [],
    'settlement_start_date' => [],
    'settlement_end_date' => [],
    'total' => []
];

foreach($resultArray as $result){
    $newArray['settlement_id'][]        = (isset($result['settlement_id'])) ? $result['settlement_id'] : '';
    $newArray['settlement_start_date'][]    = (isset($result['settlement_start_date'])) ? $result['settlement_start_date'] : '';
    $newArray['settlement_end_date'][]  = (isset($result['settlement_end_date'])) ? $result['settlement_end_date'] : '';
    $newArray['total'][]            = (isset($result['total'])) ? $result['total'] : '';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```